# Are the electrons and protons electric potential in bonded state are the same as if they are free particles?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, electric-fields, protons

During the approach of an electron and a proton into a hydrogen atom, are their electric fields unchanged? Or do they cancel each over out (more or less, only a weak electric dipole alive).

Comment: How and why  would they change? Do you mean have experiments been  done to measure them?

Comment: I think that the magnetic dipole moments of the electrons are responsible for the shells with 2, 8, 8, ... electrons and the Pauli exclusion principle (https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_atoms_Part_1). And that protons (together with neutrons) are able to be in a nucleus happens do to the cancelling out the electric fields of the involved electrons and protons (https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one-dimensional_structures_of_space). But in my question I simple want to know is the cancellation is taken in account.

Comment: Congratulations on the papers, they read extremely well,  Can you not include a reference to them in your post? If I had known about them, I would not have asked you the otherwise "simple" question. Are you allowed to put the abstracts in your post?

Comment: @CountTo10 The facts are "on the hand", but the conclusions are not mainstream, so due to the really high quality if physics.stackexchange I'm not sure that it would be good to do what you propose.

Comment: The shell structure is well described with vanilla quantum mechanics, and the Pauli Exclusion principle is predicted by the  Spin Statistics theorem which also explains why bosons are not subject to that limit.

Comment: @dmckee what is better for science, a description or an explanation of a phenomenon?

Comment: The fact that you ask that question that way suggests that you don't have any idea how deeply and fundamentally those two thing act. Neither of those things are built-to-order to explain this one thing, they both explain several things on the basis of a deeper structures. The standard description is both parsimonious and elegant, and because it makes many other predictions as well as those two it is supported by a wealth of experimental evidence. You keep trying to treat little problems in isolation when they are already understood in terms of theories that treat *many* phenomena at once.

Answer (score 1):

The [hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydsch.html#c2) is analytically solvable in the Schrödinger equation

[image: hydroge]

U(r) is the potential and the solution of the equation exists for all r. If the energy is positive it is a free electron and a free proton, if it is negative it has to be in a quantized state.

[image: hydrlevel]

Comment: U is the potential energy?

Comment: in the case of the simple electron-proton field it is the electric potential ~1/r  http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/237/hatom.php